# Why script tags in atom become grey and don't work?

Tags: javascript, html, tags, atom-editor

I'm learning code with Atom editor, so I added Bootstrap and jquery sources with two javaScript, but once added in the editor they become grey and doesn't work on the browser.
Despite this, if I run the same code on Brackets editor it works properly.

I'm using Catalina OS X

[Grey JS Tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQEmj.png)

Comment: Could you show us your code please.

Comment: @AntonioSk Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to embed a picture, but there's the link to it at the end of the post "Grey JS Tags", click on it to see the code

Comment: Do you have the bootstrap files in your file structure?

Comment: @AntonioSk Yes, in addition to what I wrote before, once saved with Brackets editor, if I open the index.html file again with atom it work. I really don't understand this behavior

Answer (score 0):

it was my case and i just disabled the "use Tree sitter Parsers" in core settings and it works
you can disabled that by
edit>preferences>core>use tree sitter parsers
and disable it